# Why does Tensorflow not get installed properly using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation

I installed tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow` on my windows 10 laptop. I have no GPU on my laptop and my CPU is Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU which supports AVX instruction sets.

However, it doesn't get installed properly.
I ran the following commands on my powershell before I encountered the error.

```
PS C:\Users\Dwij>pip install tensorflow
PS C:\Users\Dwij>python

Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

On running this, the following traceback was encountered.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Dwij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

However if I install tensorflow using conda by running `conda install tensorflow`
tensorflow works perfectly fine.

Comment: No, I had seen this answer earlier and it doesn't solve my problem. I do have Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2015-2019 installed all in a single package.

Comment: Make sure it's on your PATH, install again if needed. Your error is common for VS redistributable packages issue.